# Application crashes upon setting wallpaper on Galaxy S when installed from APK - works from Eclipse

Tags: android, crash, installation, apk, wallpaper

My app sets wallpaper correctly on HTC Incredible, but crashes on Galaxy S. This occurs only when installed through an APK file. When the app is installed through the Eclipse environment it works correctly on both the HTC Incredible and Samsung SCH-1500. When I export the app as an APK file it seems to install correctly, and all of the other functions work correctly. It is only the setting of the wallpaper that crashes. When I run using the debugger all is well - no problem. Could this be a permission issue? Why no issue on the HTC but crash on the Samsung?

Thanks for your help!
Kurt Reindel

Comment: Seeing some of the code that is causing the issue could help find the problem.

Comment: What type of crash?  A Force Close?  Do you have the debuggable attribute set to TRUE in the manifest so you can get debug output?

Comment: Memory issue?  Different phones/environments give you different amounts of heap to play with.